# Definir o lado da margin com jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

Como posso proceder para que o jQuery defina o lado da `margin` para não ocorrer o problema na imagem?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
 $('.case .show-opt').on('click', function(){
  $('.'+$(this).attr('data-type')+$(this).attr('data-number')).toggle("slow");
 });
```

```css
 .case {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #222;
  height: 0px;
  width: calc(20% - 9px);
  padding-bottom: 18%;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  box-shadow: 2px 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  margin: 4.5px;
 }
 .opt-item.t-file {
  height: 290px;
 }
 .opt-item {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 47px 10px 10px 10px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  box-shadow: 2px 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  padding: 8px;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="case">
 <div class="botoes">
  <button data-type="opfi" data-number="4" class="show-opt ion-android-more-vertical"></button>
 </div>
 <div class="opt-item t-file opfi4" style="display: none;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Qual o problema?

Comment: A margin está fazendo o scroll da pagina aparecer embaixo por conta da div .opt-item, gostaria de um script que alinha ela mais para a esquerda para tirar o scroll abaixo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode resolver verificando se o scroll aparece quando a div é exibida. O problema é que não tem como saber se o scroll aparece antes da div ser exibida no toggle. Para isso é preciso exibir a div temporariamente para detectar o scroll, mas você pode retirar o `display: none` e colocar `visibility: hidden` para que ela não seja visível. Se o scroll foi detectado, faz um recuo com `left` do tamanho do scroll + `10px` (`-scrolDiff-10 +"px"`. Esse `10` você pode aumentar se quiser afastar mais da borda direita) e aplica o `display: none` novamente com `.hide()` e restaura a propriedade `visibility`:

```
$('.case .show-opt').on('click', function(){

   var el = $('.'+$(this).attr('data-type')+$(this).attr('data-number'));

   // só se a div estiver oculta
   if(!el.is(":visible")){

      el.css("visibility", "hidden").show();

      // verifica se o scroll foi ativado
      var scrolDiff = $("html").get(0).scrollWidth - $("html").width();

      el.css({
         "left": scrolDiff > 0 ? -scrolDiff-10 +"px" : "0",
         "visibility": "visible"
      }).hide();
   }

   el.toggle("slow", function(){
      if(!el.is(":visible")) el.css("left", "0");
   });


});
```

Vou colocar 2 exemplos abaixo simulando que a `div#mobile` é a área do dispositivo, sendo o primeiro sem o código aparecendo o scroll, o segundo com o código, eliminando o scroll (mas não copie o código dos exemplos. Copie o código do início da resposta):

### Exemplo 1 (normal)

```js
$('.case .show-opt').on('click', function(){
   
   var el = $('.'+$(this).attr('data-type')+$(this).attr('data-number'));

   el.toggle("slow");
   
});
```

```css
.case {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #222;
  height: 0px;
  width: calc(20% - 9px);
  padding-bottom: 18%;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  box-shadow: 2px 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  margin: 4.5px;
 }
 .opt-item.t-file {
  height: 290px;
 }
 .opt-item {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 47px 10px 10px 10px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  box-shadow: 2px 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  padding: 8px;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
 }

#mobile{
   width: 220px;
   overflow: auto;
   height: 250px;
   border: 2px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mobile">
   <div class="case">
      <div class="botoes">
         <button data-type="opfi" data-number="4" class="show-opt ion-android-more-vertical">Abrir</button>
      </div>
      <div class="opt-item t-file opfi4" style="display: none;"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

### Exemplo 2 (sem scroll horizontal)

```js
$('.case .show-opt').on('click', function(){
   
   var el = $('.'+$(this).attr('data-type')+$(this).attr('data-number'));

   if(!el.is(":visible")){

      el.css("visibility", "hidden").show();
      
      var scrolDiff = $("#mobile").get(0).scrollWidth - $("#mobile").width();
   
      el.css({
         "left": scrolDiff > 0 ? -scrolDiff-10 +"px" : "0",
         "visibility": "visible"
      }).hide();
   }

   el.toggle("slow", function(){
      if(!el.is(":visible")) el.css("left", "0");
   });
   
});
```

```css
.case {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #222;
  height: 0px;
  width: calc(20% - 9px);
  padding-bottom: 18%;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  box-shadow: 2px 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  margin: 4.5px;
 }
 .opt-item.t-file {
  height: 290px;
 }
 .opt-item {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  margin: 47px 10px 10px 10px;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  box-shadow: 2px 1px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  padding: 8px;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
 }

#mobile{
   width: 220px;
   overflow: auto;
   height: 250px;
   border: 2px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mobile">
   <div class="case">
      <div class="botoes">
         <button data-type="opfi" data-number="4" class="show-opt ion-android-more-vertical">Abrir</button>
      </div>
      <div class="opt-item t-file opfi4" style="display: none;"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No primeiro click funciona normal, no segundo click o scrolDiff fica igual a zero e a div volta a forçar o scroll, se clicar novamente volta a funcionar

Comment: Era só colocar um callback no toggle pra voltar o `left` a `0`.